# How to have a sync and async delayed promise inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using the following library to have some delay in a promise:

```
const prom = require('util').promisify;
const delayedProm = prom(setTimeout);
```

i have two nested loops inside '.then(())', and in the inner loop there is if-condition. when this if-condition is satisfied i want to delay to certain 
amount of time, then the loop should continue normally. the promise should be resolved and returned when the two loops finish iterations.

please let me know how to achieve that sync and async

***code***:

```
return func()
.then((execs) => {

for () {
    for () {

        if (condition) {
            dely(interval)
        }
    }
}

return resolvedPromise
})
```

Comment: `please let me know how to achieve that sync and async` when working with Promises, or any asynchronous code, you can't make it `synchronous` because that defies the laws of time and space

Comment: you've created this `delayedProm` and never use it? What's the point of that?

Answer (score 0):

To use `delay` that in a loop, `await` is very useful:

```
return (async function() {
  const execs = await func();

  for () {
    for () {
      if (condition) {
        await delay(interval)
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

Read on:

[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: "At first I'm not sure that promisifying setTimeout automatically will work," - it does. Only the await is missing - you also have a typo.

Comment: @benjamin okay so it checks if the callback passes an error and rejects then? I always thought it would be `functoon callback(err, result) { if(err) reject(err); else resolve(result); }`

Comment: It has a facility - `util.promisify.custom` which functions can implement to explain how to promisify them. `setTimeout[util.promisify.custom]` tells `util.promisify` what to do - Node.js uses this to deal with non-nodeback APIs like setTimeout or `fs.exists`